# Ubuntu Server 22.04 unmounting usb external drive

Tags: server, suspend, fstab, automount, usb-drive

I have a thin client PC, running Ubuntu Server 22.04 with Jellyfin and Samba on it. As the machine have not much internal storage, I am using 8 TB external USB drive. I've set OS to automount the drive on boot via fstab and it's working fine. The issue is that when the machine gone idle for some time, it suspends the USB devices and after that they are either unmounted or are behaving strangely. I tried to turn off autosuspend using a number of tutorials, but none of them seems to do the job. The last I have tried was installing tpl and from there blacklist the HDD drive.
I am searching a way to make OS either not suspend USB drives or to automount the external drive after it was waked up.